# How to Configure JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean to consume SOAP 1.2 webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I need to consume SOAP1.2 (.NET hosted) webservice using `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`

The following is the snippet of my Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="documentUploadServiceJaxwsClient"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.tempuri.IDocumentUploadService" />
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://tempuri.org/" />
    <property name="serviceName" value="DocumentUploadService" />
    <property name="portName" value="secureBinding" />
    <property name="endpointAddress" ref="documentUploadServiceEndpointString" />
    <property name="customProperties" ref="internetProxyProperties"  />
    <property name="handlerResolver" ref="handlerResolver"/>
</bean>
```

I am using Spring 3.0.0. I dont want to go thru CXF related configuration as this is just a short term solution.

I have also tried (dirty solution) using `SOAPHandler`but Server does not allows me to change the `SOAPEnvelope` at runtime.
Sample code which I used:

`SOAPMessage sm = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL).createMessage(mimeHeaders, new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()));`

`context.setMessage(sm);`

Websphere gives me following:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WSWS4117E: An attempt was made to add an SOAPEnvelope with a protocol of SOAP 1.1 Protocol to a SOAPMessage with a protocol of SOAP 1.2 Protocol.

I also tried setting up `customproperties` but it did not helped.

I need something equivalent of

`<jaxws:binding>
    <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
</jaxws:binding>`

but by using `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`
Ideally I would like to get it working thru simple configuration.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: Got any luck with this? I am stuck on this exact issue